# Creating a non-tracking in-app web browser

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nshttpcookie

I am trying to create a webview (as an exercise) that does not track or store any browsing history locally.
I have made it so that when the webview is closed, it calls the following

```
[[NSURLSession sharedSession]resetWithCompletionHandler:^{}];
```

but I am finding that things like google search history persists some how between sessions. I have also tried clearing cookies separately through

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [storage cookies]) {
       [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

still to no avail. Google searches still show when a new web view is created.
Is anyone aware of a way to remove the identifier that google is using to match that search history back to me? I'm concerned it's something like the bundle identifier, which is probably a bit trickier to prevent being read.
Any ideas are appreciated.
Regards,
Luke

Comment: did you try cleaning the cache also ?  [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

Comment: I'm assuming so. `- (void)resetWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler;    /* empty all cookies, cache and credential stores, removes disk files, issues -flushWithCompletionHandler:. Invokes completionHandler() on the delegate queue if not nil. */`. I will try that also anyway.

Comment: Set the Wkwebviewconfiguration  websiteDataStore  as WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistentDataStore() and see if it works

Comment: Incase of NSURLConnection ... in the delegate return nil for cachedResponse in the following delegate method `-(NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse`

Comment: Or else try removing the cache `[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:request];`

Comment: As far as website request is concerned try to use `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` for `NSURLRequest`

Comment: Right on the money with the nonPersistentDataStore. If you give that as an answer, the bounty is yours mate

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try setting **nonPersistentDataStore** for **WKWebsiteDataStore** of **WKWebViewConfiguration**

Here is a sample code snippet

```
let webVuConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webVuConfiguration.websiteDataStore =WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistentDataStore()
let webView = WKWebView(frame: webviewRect, configuration: webVuConfiguration)
```

Answer (score 3):

To compliment Durai Amuthan.H's answer, here is the answer for us plebs who still like to use Obj-C

```
WKWebViewConfiguration * config = [WKWebViewConfiguration new];
config.websiteDataStore = [WKWebsiteDataStore nonPersistentDataStore];   
webView = [[WKWebView alloc]initWithFrame:viewFrame configuration:config];
```

Comment: Thanks for the compliment :) I am glad that I am of some help to you and I don't think Obj-C developers are plebs :) you know old is gold