# how to support incognito/private mode in wkwebview/uiwebview

Tags: ios, caching, nsurlsession, wkwebview, nshttpcookie

I am working on a incongnito browser.I am using wkwebview when I clear all the cookies I can see that popular search engine like google remembers the searches that has been made.

I tried cleaning all the cookies in NSHTTPCookieStorage and resetcookies using NSURLSession but its still not working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set `nonpersistentdatastore` for `wkwebsitedatastore` for `wkwebviewconfiguration` for `wkwebview`

Set  `NSURLrequestreloadcacheignoringlocalandremotecachedata` for `NSURlrequest` in `uiwebview`

Reference

[Creating a non-tracking in-app web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42994553/730807)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: We now have to use WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent() to create a non-persistent data store, then assign it to the configuration.websiteDataStore before instantiating WKWebView with the said configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Private browsing in iOS using WKWebView

**As per apple documentation**:
*To support private browsing,create a data store object and assign it to the websiteDataStore property of a WKWebViewConfiguration object before you create your web view. The default() method returns the default data store that saves website data persistently to disk. To implement private browsing, create a nonpersistent data store using the nonPersistent() method instead.*

```
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.processPool = WKProcessPool()
    webConfiguration.websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent()
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.webContainerView.bounds, configuration: webConfiguration)
    // Set up request
    if let requestURL = URL(string: "enter_url_to_load") {
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
        request.httpShouldHandleCookies = false
        request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(request)
    }
    self.webContainerView.addSubview(webView)
```